# How to write a function that would check whether two arrays are horrizontally symmetrical?

Tags: c

I am writing a program, that works like that: Give two decimal integer numbers to it. The program than finds all the integer numbers that are between those two numbers. Than the program converts all those numbers including the numbers inputted into a binary numbers and stores them in arrays. Than it find all the binary numbers that are horizontally symmetrical and print all those. Works like that:

```
2 5 //input

11 //output
101
```

So far, I did everything but I cannot find a way how to only print those arrays that are horizontally symmetric. My program looks like that so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


    int HI;
    int LO;
    char X[200]={0};
    char test_if_l_c[] = {'c','l'};
    int binaryNumNotReversed[32];
    int binaryNumFinal[32];
    int temp;

int main ()
{
    printf("Entrence intervals:\n");
    scanf("%s%d%d", X, &LO, &HI); 
    if ( X[0] != test_if_l_c[0] && X[0] != test_if_l_c[1] || X[1] != 0 || X[2] != 0 || X[3] != 0 || X[4] != 0 || HI <= LO || HI == 0 || LO == 0) 
    {
        printf("Wrong input.\n");
        return 0;   
    }

    int count_in_interval = HI - LO + 1;

    for(int u = 0; u < count_in_interval ; u++)
    {
        int particular_number = LO + u;

        //converting to binary but not reversed binary yet:
        int a = 0;
        while (particular_number > 0)
        {
            binaryNumNotReversed[a] = particular_number % 2;
            particular_number = particular_number / 2;
            a++;
        }

        //flipping binary array to the final binary number:
        int j = a - 1;
        int r = 0;
        while (j >= 0 ) //for(j = a - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
        {                               
            temp = binaryNumNotReversed[j];
            binaryNumFinal[r] = temp;
            j--;
            r++;
        }  

        //Condition that I do not know how to write which tells: if binaryNumFinal horizontally symmetrical with binaryNumNotReversed, than printf binaryNumFinal:

        if (readArray(binaryNumFinal, a) == readArray(binaryNumNotReversed, a))
        {
            for(int n = 0; n < a; n++)
            printf("%d", binaryNumFinal[n]); 
        }
        printf("\n");

    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Could you please help me to solve my problem? I am really a beginner in programming..

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so by "array" you pretty much mean string, and by "horizontally symmetric" you pretty much mean palindrome. So consider the following slightly more general program...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  int n1 = ( argc>1? atoi(argv[1]) : 1 ),
      n2 = ( argc>2? atoi(argv[2]) : 999 ),
      b1 = ( argc>3? atoi(argv[3]) : 10 ),
      b2 = ( argc>4? atoi(argv[4]) : 10 );
  int n=abs(n1), b=b1, nb=0, ispal();
  char *itoa();
  for ( n=abs(n1); n<=n2; n++ ) { nb=0;
    for ( b=b1; b<=b2; b++ )
      if ( ispal(n,b) ) { nb++; if ( n1 < 0 ) {
           if ( nb == 1 ) printf("%10d(base10)",n);
           printf(" = %s(%d)", itoa(n,b),b); }
      } else if ( n1 > 0 ) goto next_n;
    if ( n1 > 0 ) { printf("%10d(base10)",n);
      for ( b=b1; b<=b2; b++ ) printf(" = %s(%d)", itoa(n,b),b); }
    if ( nb > 0 ) printf("\n");
    next_n: ; }
  } /* --- end-of-function main() --- */
int  ispal ( int i, int base ) {
  char *itoa(), *a=itoa(i,base);
  int answer=0, k=0,n=strlen(a);
  if ( n > 1 ) {
    for ( k=0; k<n/2; k++ )
      if ( a[k] != a[n-k-1] ) goto end_of_job;
    answer = 1; }
  end_of_job: return ( answer );
  } /* --- end-of-function ispal() --- */
char *itoa ( int i, int base ) {
  static char a[99], digits[99] = /* up to base 65 */
      "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz#$*";
  int n = 0;
  while ( 1 ) {
    a[n++] = digits[i%base];
    if ( (i/=base) < 1 ) break; }
  a[n] = '\000';
  return ( a );
  } /* --- end-of-function itoa() --- */
```

The first command-line arg, n1, is your LO, and the second, n2, is HI. The additional third and fourth, b1 and b2, are the range of bases for which the integers n1<=n<=n2 must be "palindromic". So you'd choose them both as 2.

So, for example, running the program with args  **1 100 2 2** gives output

```
 3(base10) = 11(2)
 5(base10) = 101(2)
 7(base10) = 111(2)
 9(base10) = 1001(2)
15(base10) = 1111(2)
17(base10) = 10001(2)
21(base10) = 10101(2)
27(base10) = 11011(2)
31(base10) = 11111(2)
33(base10) = 100001(2)
45(base10) = 101101(2)
51(base10) = 110011(2)
63(base10) = 111111(2)
65(base10) = 1000001(2)
73(base10) = 1001001(2)
85(base10) = 1010101(2)
93(base10) = 1011101(2)
99(base10) = 1100011(2)
```

And running it with args **1 10000000 7 9** gives the single line

300(base10) = 606(7) = 454(8) = 363(9)

That is, 300 is the one-and-only number between one and ten-million that's
a palindrome in all three bases 7, 8 and 9, as illustrated. Bet you never knew that, did ya?:)

Answer (score 1):

To solve the task described you don't need arrays and you don't need to convert anything into binary. Numbers are already binary so you can simply operate directly on the numbers.

The program be shows how it can be done.

```
uint32_t findMSB(uint32_t i)
{
  uint32_t n = 31;
  while(n)
  {
    if ((1 << n) & i) return n;
    --n;
  }
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  uint32_t low = 0;
  uint32_t high = 20;
  for (uint32_t i = low; i<=high; ++i)
  {
    uint32_t msb = findMSB(i);  // Find the highest bit number where the bit == 1
    uint32_t lsb = 0;
    int sym = 1;                // Assume the number is symmetrical 
    while(lsb < msb)            // Check whether bits are equal, i.e. both 0 or both 1
    {
      int msb_val = ((1 << msb) & i) ? 1 : 0;
      int lsb_val = ((1 << lsb) & i) ? 1 : 0;
      if (msb_val != lsb_val)
      {
        sym = 0;                // Not symmetrical so clear the flag
        break;                  // No reason to continue the loop so break out
      }
      --msb;   // Move to next bits
      ++lsb;
    }
    if (sym) printf("sym: %u\n", i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sym: 0
sym: 1
sym: 3
sym: 5
sym: 7
sym: 9
sym: 15
sym: 17
```

What is left for you:

1. The program prints decimal values so you need to add a binary print
2. The program only handles unsigned values so you need to add support for signed values
3. The program has fixed limits so you need read limits as user input